# Access "Request payload" in Spring MVC Controller?

Tags: spring-mvc

How to simple as `@RequestParam` or `@PathVariable` access *"Request payload"* in Spring MVC Controller ?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `@RequestBody` (see [example](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody) in the manual).