# How to access Request Payload in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc

How can I access the Request Payload in Spring MVC ?

[image: Sample Image showing request payload]
PS: I know the question has been asked before, here : [Access "Request payload" in Spring MVC Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066138/access-request-payload-in-spring-mvc-controller?rq=1)
However, I didn't get the way it should be done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `@RequestBody`.

For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add")
public String add(@RequestBody String json, HttpServletRequest request) {
        return json;
}
```